# how to install bokken 1.8 or latest in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt

i am trying to install bokken 1.6,1.7,1.8 in ubuntu 14.04
same error accer plz help me error is here

```
najeeb@najeeb:~$ sudo apt-get install bokken 
[sudo] password for najeeb: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bokken : Depends: python-radare2 (>= 0.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Enable universe repository by http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository and try again.

Comment: no not work      no not work      no not work      no not work

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy python-radare2` and give me a ping with @A.B.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: actually bokken tool gpg key of repository is expired that provided by bokken project team . i have tried to use gpg key and repository using documentation

```
pub   3072D/233280A7 2012-01-17 [expired: 2015-01-16]
uid                  Inguma Team Archive Automatic Signing Key for 2012-2015 (3-year validity) <deb@inguma.eu>
```

you can try it their documentation [here](https://inguma.eu/projects/bokken/wiki/Debian_installation) . you can report it as a bug . 
if you want to install it then you have to download source code from [here](https://inguma.eu/projects/bokken/files)or [here](http://bokken.re/download.html)
also they put NOTICE:

```
Important! Debian and Homebrew packages are broken, use manual installation instead
```

**solution** :you have to download code and run it as explained in documentation [here](http://bokken.re/docu.html)

EDIT2: before running source code you have to install prerequisite that explained [here](https://inguma.eu/projects/bokken/wiki/Installation) 
i hope this will help better to configure

Comment: sorry but problem still there.why you try to install in your computer. i think same problem you will face.then you solve it.